# Eliminating adding CRLF to end of text while copying from DataGrid

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid, clipboard

If you copy text from WPF `DataGrid` cell (Ctrl+C), from unknown reason there is always end of line (CRLF) added to end of copied text. This can prevent correct pasting of copied text to some applications.

I tried to intercept copying using behavior and also by directly hooking to `DataGrid's` `CopyingRowClipboardContent`, both without success.

```
Protected Sub OnCopyingRowClipboardContent(sender As Object, e As DataGridRowClipboardEventArgs)
  Dim cellContent = e.ClipboardRowContent(DirectCast(sender, DataGrid).CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex)
  e.ClipboardRowContent.Clear()
  e.ClipboardRowContent.Add(cellContent)
  If Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.UnicodeText) OrElse
     Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.Text) Then
    Dim clipboardText = Clipboard.GetText()
    Dim length = clipboardText.Length
    If length >= 2 Then
      If clipboardText(length - 1) = vbLf AndAlso clipboardText(length - 2) = vbCr Then
        clipboardText = clipboardText.Substring(0, length - 2)
        Clipboard.SetText(clipboardText)
      End If
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Is there any way to copy text without added CRLF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this is probably to create a custom `DataGrid` class that overrides the `OnExecutedCopy` method:

```
public class CustomDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    protected override void OnExecutedCopy(ExecutedRoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnExecutedCopy(args);

        string text = Clipboard.GetText();
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            Clipboard.SetText(text.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty));
    }
}
```

Comment: It works! Simple and elegant solution that does not break my MVVM.

Comment: That worked! Great idea! Thank you. 
The hardest part was realizing I needed to add this to the XAML Window: `xmlns:myControls="clr-namespace:MyNamespace;assembly="` (empty assembly!) and then use it as : `<myControls:CustomDataGrid x:Name=....` (use x:Name, not Name)